# What kind of monster is this?

Tags: riddle

> Countless men spilled their blood over me
>
> Some called me a gift, some called me a burden
>
> Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form
>
> And when the bells toll, you'll remember me
>
> *Who / what am I ?*

Hint

> I always accompany the devourer of sons

---

*EDIT : to clarify, the title refers to the "dreadful" feeling of the riddle, the thing is not an actual monster.*

Comment: Is it "onion" lol?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL You know what? "Sometimes, even onions comply to me" could actually be a hint!

Comment: As promised, I added a hint

Comment: Is it relate to some video games?

Comment: @Alex : not at all :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be...

> a ring?

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> Blood is often spilled in a fighting **ring**.

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> A ring can represent marriage. Some wed for love (a gift), while some are forced into arranged marriages or marry for convenience (a burden).

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Viewing the bright **ring**, or annulus, that occurs during a total solar eclipse is an experience that can move some to tears.

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> Loud sounds, like ringing bells, can cause a prolonged ringing in the ears (i.e. tinnitus).

Hint:

> "I always accompany the devourer of sons": [as pacoverflow mentions in a comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58808/what-kind-of-monster-is-this#comment180493_58945), the Greek god [Cronus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cronus) devoured his children, and his Roman equivalent is Saturn, which is a planet encircled by **rings**.

Possible hint from comments:

> "Sometimes, even onions comply to me" may refer to how onions can be fashioned into **rings**, for eating instead of wearing.

Comment: I think devourer of sons is Cronus (Saturn), and the planet Saturn has rings.

Comment: The answer is about right, but the reasons given fit too loosely. The thing is indeed a ring but try to get away from the idea of engagement/wedding ring (except for one clue) to better fit each line ;)

Comment: @Keelhaul: Okay, but which clue is the wedding one? I'm guessing the second or third?

Comment: Third :). Second has been found in some comment and fourth not yet. Still, time to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly confident that you are:

> **TIME**

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> Countless men spilled their blood over time. In fact, every single man who had their blood spilled.

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> The gift of time, or the burden of time, refers to how one chooses to interpret the passage of time in their lives.

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Little dubious, but could refer to people crying over the time that has passed, or when they miss some date to something important, or over the joy of memories of past times.

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> Bells toll when the clock hits a specific time.

Hint too:

> "I always accompany the devourer of sons" - Cronus, the devourer of sons, is a titan that is associated with the personification of time. This could also explain the title, since Cronus's action made him seem like a monster.

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment, so this is going off of @gnovice's answer...

The answer is:

> ring

Countless men spilled their blood over me:

> a boxing *ring*

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden:

> <s>still working on this one... could this be the one related to marriage? some wed for love, others are arranged</s> bea**ring** gifts or bea**ring** a burden

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Tears were shed while cutting the onion, the simple form of an onion *ring*

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> <s>the bell leaves a *ring* in your ear</s> wedding bells *ring*, I sure hope you'd remember your spouse!

I always accompany the devourer of sons

> @pacoverflow solved this one, cronus = saturn, and the planet saturn has rings

Comment: First and last clues are right

Comment: Are the middle two on track?

Comment: No and, well, could work but this doesn't explain why you *remember me*

Comment: I'm not sure if you get updates, but I have updated the second clue

Comment: @EskimoPuddle ahh line 2 is probably referring to LOTR. A present to Bilbo, a burden to Frodo

Comment: and perhaps line 3 is referencing the halo of the eclipse

Comment: @PaigeMeinke I was thinking halo for line 3 as well, but I would have never gotten the LOTR clue. Good thinking!

Comment: I think your reference for #4 is actually the answer to #3 (well - actually - the precursor to that event!), and the answer to #4 has to do with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Funeral_toll), referenced to some degree by a famous [novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Whom_the_Bell_Tolls) ...

Comment: Second has been found in some comment, third is the only one actually related to wedding/proposal and fourth has not been found yet

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> Death

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> Men spill blood to avoid and or produce death

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> To some death is something to be celebrated however others fear death so it may be seen as a burden

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> The simple sight of most things death related can make you shed a tear, a loved one in a coffin perhaps...

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> Bells toll at a funeral, funerals are a reminder of death

Sometimes, even onions comply to me

> Even onions comply to death after being eaten or rotting

Comment: That's not it, sorry

Comment: No problem :), I've had another go after your edit

Comment: That's not it either :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> A cross?

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> The Crusades/religious wars, crucifixions, etc.

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> Some believe that JC dying on the cross was a gift to them, but I am sure that those who actually has to carry their cross to Golgotha thought of it as a burden.

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Some people cry in church

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> Church bells

Comment: It could work, but no. I have the feeling this riddle may be a little too broad, I'll probably add another clue tomorrow to narrow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> Earth/Soil?

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> Unlike today's cold wars, millions of people died fighting over lands in the past.

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> Israel for ex. claims a certain area in near its region as their promised lands. I'm not sure who calls their soil a burden.

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Still thinking on this one.

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> When the "bells toll for thee" , you will be going back to the soil.

Comment: Not this either

Answer (score 0):

My thought is

> Life

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> In fighting, you may need to kill others to save your own life, or get hurt yourself to protect others.

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> Life can be considered both a gift and a burden by some

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Tears of happiness at birth, or a baby's cries

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> Bells sound at the memorial of a deceased one

I always accompany the devourer of sons

> Life and death are always related

Comment: Nor life, nor death, nor an abstract concept

Answer (score 0):

Are you:

> Circumcise?

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> Yes...

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> a gift from god, or burden when it's over-extended

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Yes but I dunno if it's tear of joy or

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> When the church's bell toll

Answer (score 0):

Is it:

> a child

This seems to readily fit most of the clues.

Answer (score 0):

This makes me think of

> A solar eclipse

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> In less civilized times, aztecs sacrificed many people during the eclipses

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> Some people think they are special an enjoyable, but some people see them as bad omens

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> If you glance at the sun while it is being eclipsed, it will damage your eyes

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> Not sure on this one though

HINT

> I always accompany the devourer of sons - I see this as being wordplay, meaning Suns, the moon is sometimes referred as the devourer of the sun during solar eclipses. So in this case, when a moon goes to cross in front of our view of the sun, the solar eclipse will always accompany it.

Answer (score 0):

It is:

> A beard.

Countless men spilled their blood over me

> Cut when shaving!

Some called me a gift, some called me a burden

> Some men like their beard and some think it's a hassle

Tears were shed at the simple sight of my form

> Because they are feeling lazy

And when the bells toll, you'll remember me

> ???